# Inverting a tensor contraction

Tags: tensors, matrix-calculus, trace

I'm reading a paper about tensors and I come across a form like this. A and B are second order tensors, and k is a scalar. 1 is a 2nd order symmetric unit tensor, while I is a 4th order symmetric unit tensor.

$A:B = (1)Trace(B) + kB \implies A = 1\otimes1 + kI$

I am not sure how this implication works. Here is what I tried so far.

$A:B = (1)Trace(B) + kB = Trace(1\;B) + kB = B:1 + kB$

How would I obtain $A = 1\otimes1 + kI$ here?

Similar to ["Inverse" of tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380126/inverse-of-tensor-product) but with more details. The answer over there couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A:B=(kB+\ldots)$ then $A$ must be a 4th order tensor.

Given that, there are 3 extremely common and useful 4th order isotropic tensors
$$\eqalign{
 {\mathcal S}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl} \cr
 {\mathcal T}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{il}\,\delta_{jk} \cr
 {\mathcal P}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ij}\,\delta_{kl} \cr
}$$
Contracting an arbitrary matrix $B$ with each yields
$$\eqalign{
 B:{\mathcal S}&={\mathcal S}:B &= B \cr
 B:{\mathcal T}&={\mathcal T}:B &= B^T \cr
 B:{\mathcal P}&={\mathcal P}:B &= I\,\,{\rm tr}(B) \cr
}$$
For your problem, we obtain
$$\eqalign{
A = {\mathcal P} + k{\mathcal S} \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you! I think we're pretty close now. I know that the I tensor here is an average of two fourth order identity tensors (I think that is the A and B isotropic ones), and not only one as indicated here. Is there another way to write this?

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it mostly got me all the way. I am guessing maybe the average is carried out to ensure it is symmetrical? i.e. 0.5(tensor + tensor^Transpose). If you have an idea about this please let me know! And thanks again.