# Tensor product: given the result and tensor multiplication, find the tensor decomposition?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-decomposition

I am trying to code this problem: Suppose there are four elements to use when tensoring:
$$
\left\{
I = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\, 
X = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\, 
Y = \begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{bmatrix},\, 
Z = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} 
\right\},
$$

where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

The tensor product is denoted by $\otimes$ and applied on two matrices $A_{n \times n}$ and $B_{m \times m}$ as such:
$$
A\otimes B =
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}B & A_{12}B & \ldots & A_{1n}B\\
A_{21}B & A_{22}B & \ldots & A_{2n}B\\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{n1}B & A_{n2}B & \ldots & A_{nn}B\\
\end{bmatrix}_{nm\times nm}
\end{align}
$$

You are given the following:
$$
\begin{align}
A_1 &= a_{11} \otimes a_{12} \otimes \cdots \otimes a_{1n}\\
A_2 &= a_{21} \otimes a_{22} \otimes \cdots \otimes a_{2n}\\
&\phantom{~~}\vdots\\
A_m &= a_{n1} \otimes a_{m2} \otimes \cdots \otimes a_{mn}\\
\end{align},
$$
where $a_{ij} \in \{I, X, Y, Z\}$.

Let $A = A_1 * A_2 * \cdots * A_m$, where $*$ is ordinary left-to-right matrix multiplication. I would assume there is some tensor product combination that equals $A$, *i.e.,*
$$
A = a_{1} \otimes a_{2} \otimes \cdots \otimes a_{n}, \text{ where } a_i \in \{I,\, X,\, Y,\, Z\}.\\
$$
How can I find the tensor product combination of $A$?
Please keep in mind that I don't know if my assumption is correct. Furthermore, there are similar questions that have been asked such as ["Inverse" of tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380126/inverse-of-tensor-product) and [The Inverse of a Fourth Order Tensor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624955/the-inverse-of-a-fourth-order-tensor) but the details and requirements of my question differ.

Comment: What do you mean by tensor product of matrices? For instance, what would $I\otimes X$ be?

Comment: @Berci, I have edited the question! As for your request:$
I \otimes X = \begin{bmatrix}
1\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}&
0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}&
1\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Ok. But then the sizes of $A_i$ and $A$ might differ.. How could they be ever equal?

Comment: The sizes of $A_i$ are the same (say they are $n \times n$ for simplicity). The size of $A$ is also $n \times n$ because it is the matrix multiplication (not tensoring) of all $A_i$s.

Comment: This fails even in the case where $n=1$; just take $A_1=a_{11}=X$, $A_2=a_{21}=Y$ then $A_1 A_2$ falls outside your set. Surely you need to extend the set to be the full quaternion group?